# Windows 7 incompatible applications

Tags: windows-7

Can you name the applications you used (couldn't use) on Windows 7 that had compatibility issues with the operating system? (One application per answer please.)

Answer (score 2):

[Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/) current has an issue with Windows 7.  There is apparently an updated driver floating around to fix it, but it's not part of the standard install right now.

Comment: 7 says there's an issue, but I've not had any problems with it lately. Older builds refused to install properly, but the latest works just fine.

Comment: VirtualCloneDrive (http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) is better anyway. It's also free, butt doesn't try to install adware and has a more flexible license policy, which allows use in a commercial environment.

Comment: I agree, I posted about Virtual CloneDrive in another question about burning on Windows 7.  I use it now and it works great on x64.

Comment: People seriously need to stop using Daemon Tools! Bundled crapware/adware is not to be tolerated.

Comment: I posted a workaround in my blog to get Daemon Tools working on Win 7
 http://tinyurl.com/n9fawa

Answer (score 2):

[DVDFab](http://www.dvdfab.com/) - Will periodically result in a BSOD, however if you run in compatibility mode for Windows XP(SP3) it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Starcraft tends to hang the system for no apparent reason at times. Was that way in the Beta and continued to be so in the RC. DOn't know about RTM. The funny thing is, everything else still seemed to work (I could still talk on Skype, although admittedly Skype is as evil as you can get) but no input whatsoever seemed to work anymore.

I didn't try killing the game from remote, though.

So currently I'm using a VM with an ancient Windows to play in :)

Comment: That's weird. I'm able to play Starcraft on the RC fine. My only real problem with it is that the splash screen's color is not right but it doesn't hang on up my system.

Comment: Well, colors are messed up sometimes but that dates back at least until Vista or XP but that's not really a problem and in-game it doesn't appear usually. I am using an x64 version of Win 7, though.

Answer (score 1):

Any application that requires MDAC will have troubles with 64 versions of Vista and Windows 7. Since 64 bits will slowly become mainstream, most of those apps will fail due to MS not releasing a 64 bit MDAC.

Answer (score 1):

The software firewall built into F-Secure Internet Security 2009 will fail to detect most applications. Also, the heuristics will complain about Windows 7 components every few seconds, so you'll need to turn it off. The beta version seems to work fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

Miro (http://www.getmiro.com/) doesn't work correctly. Video playback is blocky and pixelated. Other player (WMP, Media player classic) work well. Tried to update the graphic driver but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Partition Magic doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2003 is an epic FAIL...

My machine doesn't support virtual XP mode, but I'd love to hear in the comments if anyone has any positive experiences running VS2003 in XP mode.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all anti-virus software doesn't work, and will need a new version with Windows 7 support to work. I've used both McAfee and Symantec on Windows 7 for work, and both have major issues on Windows 7. McAfee randomly causes a BSOD when doing an on-access scan, while Symantec causes a BSOD at boot. I've heard most other virus scanners have similar issues, although I haven't used them.

Comment: I heard Avira Antivir got along with Windows 7.

Comment: Really? All anti-virus and firewall software that has worked on Vista has also worked on Windows 7 for me.

Answer (score 1):

[The KMPlayer](http://www.kmplayer.com/) doesn't seem to work well in Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

Comment: Works on Win 7 32-bit with a couple of bugs like file associations not sticking.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having problems opening PDF links with Adobe Reader 9.1.  This, despite the fact that Adobe actually recognized that I was using Windows 7. :p

PDF X-Change works fine, though I hate the interface.